# SQl select then use the results as a where on another table

Tags: sql

Hi i have very little sql writing experience i am trying to do a simple select from one table then update another

so for example

```
select id from customer where name like 'Test'
```

then for each id it finds as there may be more than one

```
update customeractive set active=0 where id= "from the last table"
```

Comment: what Database engine?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as:

```
update customeractive
    set active=0
    where id in (select id from customer where name like 'Test');
```

This is standard SQL and will work in any database.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE customeractive
SET active=0
WHERE id IN 
(
    SELECT id
    FROM customer
    WHERE name LIKE 'Test'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update customeractive
    set active = 0
from customeractive act
    inner join customer cust on act.id = cust.id
where cust.name like 'Test'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you can do something like Selecting the IDs you want in a temporary table and then Updating the IDs you want.

In your exemple:

```
Select ID into #TempTable from Customer Where name like 'Teste'

Update   CustomerActive
Set    active = 0
Where Id in
(Select ID from #TempTable).
```

Another Way of Doing it is using Joins

```
Update    CustomerActive
Set active = 0
From CustomerActive CA
Join Customer C
On CA.ID = C.ID
Where C.name like 'Test'
```

If you are not using SQL Server, you can use the same concept. Just check how it can be done on other languages.

Hope it can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft SQL server, the other way of doing it is:

```
UPDATE customeractive
SET active=0
from customeractive join customer on customeractive.id=customer.id
where name like '% Test%'
```

And by the way I think you probably mean to use wild cards (such as %) in the LIKE statement